# Linux - SSH Restricting users to certain folders

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I am trying to create a support user who should only be able to view the following folders when SSHing into this linux box but should not be able to see any other folder. They would need to cd into the following for access.

```
/var/www/html
/var/log/nginx
```

What would be the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: What flavour of Linux are you using?

Comment: @Burgi CentOS .

Comment: They should also be able to see a good deal of `/usr`, `/bin`, and `/etc`,  otherwise they won't be able to execute anything.

Comment: @xenoid Yea that is fair, i was just referring to them folders specifically to be able to read log files.

Answer (score 0):

So if you do not want to run any applications probably accurate will be only SFTP access. Anyway run **chroot** environment for that user and give him access to these two directories by doing:

```
mount --bind /var/www/html ~user/var-html
```

Before you do that provide the appropriate permissions and make mountpoint `mkdir ~user/var-html`

Answer (score 0):

One of the Simple way is just create a user with the home directory of the path you want to give

**useradd -d /var/www/html username**

One more suggestion is to create a soft link of the path into the home directory of the user

**ln -s /var/www/html /home/username/linkname**